# android emulator: issue with dns resolution while connecting though a proxy

Tags: android, proxy, dns, android-emulator

Here is my situation:
- i m in a compagny behind a proxy
- my dns (set up in ipconfig/all) van only resolve internal domains/hosts

When i use my internrt browser (with proxy) all is fine. I can see in wireshark captures, my browser speaks with my proxy. ALL DNS resolution are made by the proxy

When i use emulator (with proxy set up in command line), i can see in wireshark DNS resolution is made locally instead of calling proxy first

So of course it cant work.

Somebody have any idea for workaround?
(I mean a real idea...no need to speak about dns-server optoon)

Thks!!!